# Initialize viewer without toolbar using ViewingApplication

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We currently use the following method to initialize the viewer:

```
viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('MyViewerDiv');
viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D, config3d);
```

Once the viewer is initialized we then remvoe the toolbar. But the toolbar is visible while the model is loading in and then it is removed which is a little confusing for our users.

Is there a config setting we can pass that will hide the toolbar by default?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get a UI-less experience by registering `Viewer3D` instead of `GuiViewer3D`. The latter is just a subclass of the former with added UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Headless viewer instead.

```
viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D, config3d);
```

You can see more about it here 
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/headless/